# What is the effect of calling a function without using its return value?

Tags: c, function, user-defined-functions

Suppose a function is declared to return a value, as in `int f(void);`. When this function is used, shouldn’t its return value be assigned to a variable, as int `int x = f();`, or otherwise used? What is the meaning of `f();` as a statement by itself?

Comment: Where did you see this sentence? What parts of this sentence do you understand already and which parts are unclear to you? Please [edit] the question to fill in these missing details.

Comment: I means what happened when I can not asign a return value of a function in a variable

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the caller. If you care about the return value then you have to do something:

```
if (doesFileExist(filename))
{
     /* do something with the file */
}
```

If you don't care then you don't need to.

```
printf("Hello\n");
/* You did know printf returns an int didn't you? */
```